# Solving a differential equation with a complex (independent) varible

Tags: differential-equations, complex

I'm trying to plug in complex values in the numerical solutions of ODEs without success. For instance

```
y[I] /. NDSolve[{y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 3}, y, {x, -10, 10}]
```

doesn't give the $3$ I'm expecting. Is there a way to work with a complex variable $x$ in NDSolve?

Thanks!

Comment: The underlying algorithms can only deal with real independent variables, I'm afraid. Why not make a substitution that incorporates the contour along which you want to integrate?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I see. What contour are you referring to? the one from $0$ to $i$?

Comment: Yes, that.$\phantom{}$

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I can indeed do that. But this is a relatively simple example. I don't think it's that simple when you have higher order, more complicated ODEs. I must say I'm surprised that mathematica has no tools to deal with such things. Do you know of any other mathematical software that do?

Comment: None offhand; most users of DE solvers might consider complex-valued ODEs, but not ODEs with complex independent variables. Anyway, can you give an example of an ODE where you think a variable substitution will be unwieldy?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Well. I'm currently looking into the Painlevé equations in the complex plane. The first one is $y''=6y^2-x$. I wanted to see how its poles are distributed but couldn't plug in complex values for $x$.

Comment: Oh my... exactly one of the things I've been looking into in my spare time. P-I is already a bit difficult. Anyway, you've seen the paper by Fornberg and Weideman, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27310/discussion-between-user1337-and-guess-who-it-is).